# Standard inputs not being added to Angularjs Form $Scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, angular-directive

Alrighty, so some back story. We are using Angularjs 1.3.15 for our application and are dynamically adding form elements to a form. When viewing the form's scope the normal input elements are not there but the ui-select and tags-input elements are. Below is the directive code and the code for one of the templates for our dynamic elements.

*This is the directive code*

```
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope , iElement, iAttrs) {

          var display = iAttrs.data;

          $http.get('views/templates/tripTemplates/' + display, {cache: $templateCache}).success(function(tplContent){
            iElement.replaceWith($compile(tplContent)(scope));                
          });              
        } 
    }
```

*This is the element code*

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" step="any" min="{{field.MinValue}}" 
name="{{field.FieldId}}" max="{{field.MaxValue}}" 
ng-required="{{field.Required}}" ng-model="Trip[field.FieldId]" 
ng-change="makeDirty(field.FieldId); setDirty(field);" ng-disabled="locked == true">
```

*This is where the directive is being used*

```
<form name="trip_form_constraints.trip" role="form" class="form-validation" data-ng-submit="save(Trip)">
        <div class="panel-body" style="margin-bottom:9px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row" ng-repeat="row in Rows">
                    <div ng-repeat="field in row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-{{field.Width}} col-lg-{{field.Width}}" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
                            <label tabindex="-1">{{field.Label}}</label>
                            <div>
                                <display-element data="{{field.Template}}"></display-element>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-w-md btn-gap-v btn-success" value="Save" ng-disabled="tripSaveDisabled" ng-if="Locked == false"/>
            <div ng-if="Form.Name == 'Charter Ticket'">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="" data-tooltip="If there is no catch to add, proceed to submitting this trip." data-tooltip-placement="right" data-tooltip-append-to-body="true">Is this a trip with no catch?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
       </form>
```

*Working Template html*

```
<ui-select ng-model="Trip[field.FieldId]" name="{{field.FieldId}}" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="{{field.Required}}" ng-if="field.Data.length > 1 && field.ParentFieldId != 0" ng-change="makeDirty(field.FieldId)" ng-disabled="locked == true">
    <ui-select-match allow-clear="true">{{$select.selected.Name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="data.Id as data in field.Data | filter: $select.search | filter: filterByParent(field.ParentFieldId)">
        <div ng-bind-html="data.Name | highlight:$select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I have tried using ng-forms and nested forms. I have also tried creating a form list such as myForm.form but that did not work. I even upgraded to angular 1.4.5 but that did not help either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am also using a $timeout to ensure the form is fully loaded before examining the form.

Here is the plunkr showing that a normal input element is not added to the form. You can console.log to see the full form or fill out the numbers portion and click save. This will then add all elements attached to the form's scope to the array at the bottom. Hope this helps.
http://plnkr.co/edit/C4ysZwEqjhaUA89vxjWP?p=preview

Comment: can you provide sample plunkr?

Comment: What kind of standard inputs?

Comment: If you can't create a jsfiddle or plunkr / add an element template that does work to compare.

Comment: I will get to work on the plunkr and post when it is done. The standard inputs are things like <input type="number"> and a date-picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out what was happening. We ended up using the ng-forms directive and creating two different named forms, a primary and a secondary form. After this, the secondary form allowed us to do client side form input errors.